# Uploading file using angular js not working

Tags: php, angularjs

I have a small app to upload files using angular js and php as server side. But I am not getting it. It shows error in the php file. Below is my code. Please help me.. thank you. I am afraid that there is some problem with the php file

HTML

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>File Upload Demo</title>

 <!-- 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="directives.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="FileUploadController">
    <h2>File Upload Demo</h2>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="myFileField">Select a file: </label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" demo-file-model="myFile"  class="form-control" id ="myFileField"/>
                </div>
                <button ng-click="uploadFile()" class = "btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>{{serverResponse}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js file

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);


    myApp.directive('demoFileModel', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A', 

            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var model = $parse(attrs.demoFileModel),
                    modelSetter = model.assign; //define a setter for demoFileModel

                //Bind change event on the element
                element.bind('change', function () {
                    //Call apply on scope, it checks for value changes and reflect them on UI
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        //set the model value
                        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    });



myApp.controller('FileUploadController', function ($scope, fileUploadService) {

        $scope.uploadFile = function () {
            var file = $scope.myFile;
            var uploadUrl = "upload.php", //Url of webservice/api/server
                promise = fileUploadService.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);

            promise.then(function (response) {
                $scope.serverResponse = response;
            }, function () {
                $scope.serverResponse = 'An error has occurred';
            })
        };
    });

myApp.service('fileUploadService', function ($http, $q) {

        this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file, uploadUrl) {
            //FormData, object of key/value pair for form fields and values
            var fileFormData = new FormData();
            fileFormData.append('file', file);

            var deffered = $q.defer();
            $http.post(uploadUrl, fileFormData, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}

            }).success(function (response) {
                deffered.resolve(response);

            }).error(function (response) {
                deffered.reject(response);
            });

            return deffered.promise;
        }
    });
```

php file

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if (isset($_FILES['file'])  )
{


    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
    $newfilename = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . end($temp);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'images/' . $newfilename);

// give callback to your angular code with the image src name
    // echo json_encode($newfilename);
    echo ("sent");
}
else
{
    echo ("no");    
}

?>
```

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: angular.js:10765 POST upload.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Is your request sent ? are you sure you can contact the php file? try returning a simple value from it maybe, to make sure the communication is ok.

Comment: Your PHP file has no syntax issue. Is it being served?

Comment: ya. nothing wrong in this. my folder permission is not set in php settings in my web server. now its working... thanks, hope this may help someone when they are stuck somewhere. thanks to everyone